# Wrapping C++ functions into blocks

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

In my app i have a C++ class and an Objective-c class working together the following way:

PingPong.h

```
#ifndef __RSSCPPCallbackTest__PingPong__h
#define __RSSCPPCallbackTest__PingPong__h

#include <iostream>

class PingPong
{
public:
    static void requestPingPongWithText(std::string text);
    static void eventRequestPingPongWithTextSuccess(std::string successString);
    static void eventRequestPingPongWithTextFailure(std::string failureString);
};

#endif
```

PingPong.cpp

```
#ifndef __RSSCPPCallbackTest__PingPong__m
#define __RSSCPPCallbackTest__PingPong__m

#include "PingPong.h"

void PingPong::requestPingPongWithText(std::string text)
{
    if (text.compare("ping") == 0)
    {
        PingPong::eventRequestPingPongWithTextSuccess("success ping");
    }
    else
    {
        PingPong::eventRequestPingPongWithTextFailure("failure pong");
    }
}

#endif
```

Objective-C class: MainViewController.mm

```
@implementation MainViewController

        /* init, viewDidLoad, etc... */

        // Call ping with a button
        - (IBAction)sayPing:(id)sender {

            NSString *text = @"ping";

            PingPong::requestPingPongWithText([text UTF8String]);
        }

        // Call pong with another button
        - (IBAction)sayPong:(id)sender {

            NSString *text = @"pong";

            PingPong::requestPingPongWithText([text UTF8String]);
        }    

@end

        void PingPong::eventRequestPingPongWithTextSuccess(std::string successString)
        {
            NSLog(@"successString: %@", [NSString stringWithCString:successString.c_str()
                                                           encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]);
        }
        void PingPong::eventRequestPingPongWithTextFailure(std::string failureString)
        {
            NSLog(@"failureString: %@", [NSString stringWithCString:failureString.c_str()
                                                           encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]);
        }
```

This works fine. What i would like to do finally is to wrap this into a function with a completion block looking like:

```
    [self requestPingPongWithText: text
    completion:^(NSString *successString, NSString *failureString)) completion {
     if (successString) {
NSLog(@"successString: %@", successString); } 
    else if (failureString) { 
NSLog(@"failureString: %@", failureString); }
    }];
```

How can i wrap up my existing code to have a function looking like above?

Comment: I don't quite understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets make a new typdef in PingPong.h:

`typedef void (^OnComplete)(std::string successString, std::string failureString);`

Make a new method for the request by block:

```
static void requestPingPongWithBlock(std:string text, OnComplete block);
```

another way, to make it explicit:

```
static void requestPingPongWithBlock(std:string text, void (^block)(std::string successString, std::string failureString));
```

implementation in PingPong.cpp:

```
void PingPong::requestPingPongWithBlock(std::string text, OnComplete block)
{
    if (text.compare("ping") == 0)
    {
        block("success ping", "");
    }
    else
    {
        block("", "failure pong");
    }   
}
```

in MainViewController.mm

```
-(void)requestPingPongWithText:(NSString*)text completion:(OnComplete) compblock{
    PingPong::requestPingPongWithBlock([text UTF8String],compblock);
}
```

and you can call it like this way:

```
[self requestPingPongWithText: text
                   completion:^(std::string successString, std::string failureString) {
                       if (successString.length() != 0) {
                           NSLog([NSString stringWithUTF8String: successString.c_str()]); }
                       else if (failureString.length() != 0) {
                           NSLog([NSString stringWithUTF8String: failureString.c_str()]); }
                   }];
```

I hope it was helpful ;)